# Extrair informações de uma tupla e colocar em variaveis distintas

Tags: python, json, tabela-banco-de-dados

sou iniciante e estou travado em um problema que nem sei como pesquisar direito.

Acontece o seguinte:
Meu codigo precisa selecionar os dados de uma tabela do banco de dados (até aqui tudo bem), e posteriormente precisa separar os dados em outras variaveis pois vou montar um json para enviar as informações para o dynamoDB.

Preciso saber como extraio as informações da minha variavel que recebeu todos os dados da minha tabela.

E se possivel, como faço para meu json enviar todas as linhas da mesma.

Se alguem tiver pelo menos algum material para eu dar uma lida e ter um norte, seria de muita ajuda. Obrigado!

```py
#######################################################
####ETAPA - BUSCANDO INFORMAÇÕES NO FIREBIRD########
#######################################################
print('ETAPA - BUSCANDO INFORMAÇÕES NO FIREBIRD')


##Executar select
try:

    sql = "SELECT * FROM USUARIO"
    cursor.execute(sql);
    USUARIO = cursor.fetchall()

except Exception as e:
    print('')
finally:
    print(USUARIO)

    somedict = {"USU_ID": [x[0] for x in USUARIO],
                "USU_NOME": [x[0] for x in USUARIO],
                "USU_USUARIO": [x[0] for x in USUARIO]
                }

print(somedict)

#######################################################
####SEPARANDO INFORMAÇÕES PARA CRIAR ARQUIVO JSON########
#######################################################

USU_ID = somedict[USU_ID]
USU_NOME = somedict[USU_NOME]
USU_USUARIO = somedict[USU_USUARIO]


###################################################
##ETAPA - CHAMANDO API PARA POST##################
###################################################
#print('MONTANDO ARQUIVO JSON PARA POST')

payload = {
    "USU_ID":USU_ID,
    "USU_NOME":USU_NOME,
    "USU_USUARIO":USU_USUARIO

}

print(str(payload))
try:
    ENVINDO POST PARA API
    url = 'https://l.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/gravar'
    print('URL API Post: ', url)
    headers = {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

except Exception as e:
   print('ERRO ac chamar API para o POST')

finally:
      print('O POST foi bem sucedido')
      print(response.text)
```

[image: Essa é a tabela que estou copiando para dentro da variavel USUARIOS]

[image: Esse é o retorno do print da variavel usuarios]

Comment: Consegue mostrar o que `USUARIO` te retorna? Assim fica mais fácil testar seu código. Outra coisa: por que você usa exceções apenas para printar algo na tela? E mais: por que usar `Exception as e` se você não usa o `e`?

Comment: Qual é o JSON que precisa enviar?

Comment: @MuriloSitonio estou reutilizando um código, por isso tem o 'exception as' sem o 'e'. Eu printo na tela para entender oq esta acontecendo no código rs.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss então, estava lendo e parece que para transformar minha variavel um array de json (n sei se isso faz sentido), precisaria transformar essa tupla em uma lista.. o modelo do JSON é um que aprendi e testei para imputar no dynamoby. Nao sei se respondi corretamente oq vc questionou...

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss talvez isso ajude a entender, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000536/convert-list-of-objects-to-json-array, o cara que postou isso, no meio da pergunta tem o modelo de matriz json que eu precisaria, pois deve ser um json para cada linha da minha tabela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[edit 2]** Pelo que eu vejo, o Python está retornando uma lista[], dentro desta lista, tem várias tuplas(), e dentro das tuplas tem os valores. Bom você pode fazer assim.

```
# Vou considerar que o seu retorno é este:
lista = [(1,'ADMINISTRADOR','ADMIN','CIENTISTA'),(2,'CEO','USER','PROGRAMADOR'),(3,'ALEATÓRIO','USER','BIÓLOGO')]

# Retorna a primeira tupla dentro da lista -> (1, 'ADMINISTRADOR', 'ADMIN', 'CIENTISTA')
print(lista[0])

# Retorna o terceiro item da tupla 2 -> 'USER'
print(lista[1][2])
```

Você pode usar loops para buscar valores, digamos que você queira ver todos os cargos, como:

- ADMINISTRADOR
- CEO
- ALEATÓRIO

Você pode criar um loop assim:

```
# Ande por todas as tuplas da lista retornada
for x in lista:
    # Mostre todos os valores nas posições 1
    print(x[1])
```

O retorno será este:

- ADMINISTRADOR
- CEO
- ALEATÓRIO

Assim você já pode ter uma noção de como brincar com estes dados. Fui direto ao ponto, espero ter ajudado. Recomendo uma estudada em listas, tuplas e dicionários no python3.

Comment: Gabriel, sua resposta foi importante para eu criar um norte aqui e estudar as possibilidades. Irei aplicar no meu código e verificar se consigo resolver. Obrigado pelo seu tempo!

Comment: @RodolfoSousa A sua [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/234323) feita nesta resposta não foi apropriada. Se tem outra dúvida, mesmo que esteja relacionada, então por favor [**faça outra pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (ou edite a pergunta atual, caso ainda seja relativo ao mesmo problema). Vc pode até colocar um link para esta resposta (caso faça outra pergunta), se ajudar a dar mais contexto para a sua dúvida. Mas não adicione novas dúvidas nas respostas existentes.

Comment: @Gabriel, sua resposta foi muito util pois eu consegui entender a logica das listas e tuplas, isso me vez ir par ao segundo nivel que seria automatizar esse codigo. Coloquei uma segunda duvida no site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/397041/automatizar-get-de-uma-lista-de-tuplas-para-vari%c3%a1veis-json .

Comment: Perfeito, a diferença básica é que listas são mutáveis, você pode mudar os valores de boa, já as duplas são permanentes, o Gustavo Guanabara pode te dar uma ótima ajuda nisso. https://youtu.be/N1hTsbW50eM

Answer (score 0):

Acho que antes de tudo, você deveria dar um passo atrás e estudar sobre como [manipular listas](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/) (você está atribuindo sempre a mesma lista a todos os campos em `somedict`) e como um [JSON é estruturado](http://www.json.org/) (primeiro você armazena um array (embora que o sempre o mesmo) e depois não). Como você não especificou de que jeito você quer que seu JSON seja estruturado vou colocar duas maneiras abaixo:

## Armazenando cada coluna em um array:

```
payload = {
            "USU_ID": [x[0] for x in USUARIO],
            "USU_NOME": [x[1] for x in USUARIO],
            "USU_USUARIO": [x[2] for x in USUARIO]
            }
```

## Separando as informações por usuário

```
payload_all = {"user_1": {
                "USU_ID": USUARIO[0][0],
                "USU_NOME": USUARIO[0][1],
                "USU_USUARIO": USUARIO[0][2]
                },
            "user_2": {
                "USU_ID": USUARIO[1][0],
                "USU_NOME": USUARIO[1][1],
                "USU_USUARIO": USUARIO[2][2]
                },
            "user_3": {
                "USU_ID": USUARIO[2][0],
                "USU_NOME": USUARIO[2][1],
                "USU_USUARIO": USUARIO[2][2]
                },
            "user_4": {
                "USU_ID": USUARIO[3][0],
                "USU_NOME": USUARIO[3][1],
                "USU_USUARIO": USUARIO[3][2]
                },
            "user_5": {
                "USU_ID": USUARIO[4][0],
                "USU_NOME": USUARIO[4][1],
                "USU_USUARIO": USUARIO[4][2]
                }
            }
```

Comment: Oi Murilo. Muito obrigado pela resposta. Irei estudar sim (já estou fazendo isso). Vou me basear na sua resposta para ter um norte. Basicamente eu preciso popular minha tabela no DYNAMOBY, ou seja resumidamente preciso pegar a tabela do firebird e imputar no DYNAMODB, ainda nao entrou na minha cabeça como faço isso funcionar, sempre que rodar o script, ele ir na tabela e pegar todas as linhas para montar o JSON.

Comment: Qual o problema que obteu com os payloads acima?

Comment: Então, no meu cenário, eu teria que automatizar, para ele montar esse payload_all. Da forma que ele retire todas as linhas das tabelas. Isso será um script no futuro, imaginamos que a tabela sempre terá atualização, meu código terá que percorrer a primeira linha da tabela até a ultima. Pois, terei uma tabela idêntica no DYNAMOBD que receberá essas informações. Além disso preciso que ele monte a matriz do JSON para poder enviar para o dynamodb. Vou dar uma estudada a fundo nisso, nao sei se fui claro no meu objetivo.

Comment: Porque você **sempre** terá que percorrer todas as linhas? Basta passar as linhas existentes para o Dynamo e atualizá-lo quando seu banco de dados tiver alguma entrada nova. O que é uma "matriz do JSON"? A variável `payload` é uma estrutura no formato JSON.

Comment: Tenho um banco de dados de inventarios (contagem de produtos). hoje o software grava as informações no firebird, a cada nova contagem o banco é zerado. Por isso o script, ele irá 'clonar' as tabelas pois vou usar as informações em outro local e irei puxar do dynamoDB. essa tabela usuarios é uma tabela simples do sistema que peguei para desenvolver a logica, mas a tabela complexa é propriamente da contagens dos produtos, que pode variar até umas 40 mil linhas. Por isso estou tentando bolar uma logica que pegue as informações da minha tabela, monte o json com todas as linhas. mt coisa :\

Comment: Agora entendi melhor. Considere incluir o máximo de informações possíveis para fazer uma [boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Sempre que vou utilizar um banco NoSQL opto pelo Mongo, então talvez não consiga ajudar muito mais. De qualquer maneira, o Dynamo também é orientado a documentos, certo? Você pretende, então, incluir todas essas 40mil linhas num único documento? (Visto que você indicou a estrutura `payload_all`...)

Comment: Murilo, me corrija caso eu esteja falando besteira mas como um json é formado por chave e valor, eu teria que ter um resultado parecido com [{'USU_ID': 1}, {'USU_NOME': "TESTE"}, {'USU_USUARIO': "ADMINISTRADOR"}, isso para cada linha da minha tabela.

Comment: Me desculpa, realmente nao consegui ser objetivo. Mas é isso mesmo, eu preciso incluir todas as linhas em um unico documento JSON para o post