# Automatizar get de uma lista de tuplas para variáveis JSON

Tags: python, json

estou com um codigo que busca informações em uma lista de tupla, o codigo está bem simples, ele está buscando as info no indice [0] e colocando nas minhas variaveis para o POST.
Eu precisaria automatizar ele para ele fazer o processo com todos os itens da lista, até acabar. 
Alguém tem alguma ideia de como poderia fazer ? O que me confunde mais é por conta do mapeamento dos indices, como eu encaixo isso em um 'for' ou em um 'While' para o codigo entender que ele precisa fazer isso ate acabar as tuplas da minha lista ?

Estou colocando o código e a foto do meu dynamodb com o meu primeiro post usando este código.

```
import requests

#aqui está minha lista de tuplas
lista = [(1, 'ADMINISTRADOR', 'ADMIN'), (2, 'CEO', 'USER'), (3, 'ALEATÓRIO', 'USER')]

#aqui busco o primeiro valor da minha tupla
id_user = lista[0][0]
nome_user = lista[0][1]
tipo_user = lista[0][2]

#aqui começo a montar o JSON para o post
payload = {
            "id": id_user,
            "nome": nome_user,
            "usuario": tipo_user

            }
try:
    #ENVINDO POST PARA API
    url = 'https://lssy4bswv8.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/gravar'
    print('URL API Post: ', url)
    headers = {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
finally:
    print('FINISH')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Praticamente resolvi meu problema com um laço. Eu sempre pego a posição 0 da minha lista porém no final do script eu excluo o índice 0, ou seja, meu código pega o novo índice 0 que antes era 1 até acabar.

```
import requests
```

## Aqui está minha lista de tuplas

```
lista = [(1, 'ADMINISTRADOR', 'ADMIN'), (2, 'CEO', 'USER'), (3, 'ALEATÓRIO', 'USER')]
```

## Aqui busco o primeiro valor da minha tupla

```
cont = len(lista)

while cont > 0:

    id_user = lista[0][0]
    nome_user = lista[0][1]
    tipo_user = lista[0][2]


    #aqui começo a montar o JSON para o post
    payload = {
            "id": id_user,
            "nome": nome_user,
            "usuario": tipo_user
                }

    try:
        #ENVINDO POST PARA API
        url = 'https://lssy4bswv8.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/gravar'
        print('URL API Post: ', url)
        headers = {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  'Accept': 'application/json'
              }
        response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    finally:
        print('FINISH')

    lista.pop(0)
```